# Kingfisher Image takes full width

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, kingfisher

I am loading images from URLs with the `KFImage` of the **Kingfisher** Library.
There is the probability that some URLs are invalid. So Kingfisher will not be able to load an image from this url. In this case i would like to collapse the `KFImage`.

```
HStack(alignment: .top) {
    KFImage(someUrl)
    Text("some Text")
}
```

In this case the KFImage takes all place it can take. I found a solution with the onSuccess Listener of KFImage.

```
KFImage(url)
    .onSuccess { _ in
       self.canLoadImage = true
    }
    .forceRefresh()
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .cornerRadius(20)
    .clipped()
    .frame(width: canLoadImage ? 150 : 0)
}
```

In this case the Image collapses and on Failure but has a width on Success. But this solution seems too complex to be the best solution possible. Since i am quiet new iOS development my ideas for better solutions are quiet limited.

Comment: Is your solution not working?

Comment: @Timmy my solution is working. but it seems unnecassary complex to me. and i wonder why i cannot just set a maxWidth to KFImage for example. When  i set maxWidth it always takes maxWidth. probabyl there is another nice solution i did not come up with so fare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can completely remove the image from the `View` using an if statement:

```
if canLoadImage {
    KFImage(url)
        .onSuccess { _ in
            self.canLoadImage = true
        }
        .forceRefresh()
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .clipped()
        .frame(width: 150)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really clear what do you want, but if you want to remove it on failure completely (instead of decrease some size) just make it conditional, like

```
@State private var imageVisible = true

...

HStack(alignment: .top) {
    if imageVisible {
      KFImage(someUrl)
        .onFailure { _ in
            imageVisible = false
        }
    }
    Text("some Text")
}
```